# Error when running ansible-playbook

Tags: ubuntu, ansible

I've installed Ansible 1.2.3 on Ubuntu Precise 64.

Running `ansible-playbook -i ansible_hosts playbook.yml` give me this error:

```
ERROR: problem running ansible_hosts --list ([Errno 8] Exec format error)
```

Here's the content of `ansible_hosts`:

```
[development]
localhost   ansible_connection=local
```

and `playbook.yml`:

```
---
- hosts: development
  sudo: yes
  tasks:
    - name: install curl
      apt: pkg=curl update_cache=yes
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 22):

For me, the problem was solved by removing "execute" permission on the ansible files (playbook, inventories etc):

```
find . -type f -exec chmod -x {} \;
```

Comment: This worked for me. Why wouldn't it be okay to have execute permissions on those files?

Comment: Good question. Unsure

Comment: Execute permission tells ansible you are trying want the inventory file to be dynamic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26859360/cant-use-ansible-inventory-file-because-it-is-executable/26863968?noredirect=1#comment42326480_26863968

Comment: Worked for me, problems started after running the command: sudo vagrant up --provision

Answer (score 11):

I have a similar problem:

```
$ ansible --version
```

> ansible 1.5.4

```
$ ansible-playbook -i hosts main.yml
```

> ERROR: problem running /mnt/d/Works/ansible-zipkin/hosts --list ([Errno 8] Exec format error)

My steps for Debian/Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge ansible
$ sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ansible/ansible
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install ansible
$ ansible --version
```

> ansible 2.2.1.0

```
$ ansible-playbook -i hosts main.yml
```

Now it works!!!

Answer (score 6):

you have to remove execution rights on `ansible_hosts`

```
chmod a-x ansible_hosts
```

if this doesn't work. try it with sudo

```
sudo chmod a-x ansible_hosts
```

Comment: Also keep in mind that in vagrant, if these files are mounted in Windows (config.vm.synced_folder) then chmod does not work. I ended copying the entire folder so that I could run chmod on the inventory files.

Comment: Right, if you are running vagrant from a Windows system, then you wont be able to run chmod directly under the /vagrant shared folder.In such a case, you will need to copy/move the files away from the /vagrant directory.

Answer (score 3):

Execute permissions are used for dynamic inventory scripts like for example `rax.py`. 
This one in particular builds an inventory by getting it from RackSpace.
If you're maintaining your inventory manually your inventory file should not be executable.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this and solved it by using `shell` instead of `command`.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed with ansible 2.0 https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/10068

Answer (score -1):

I am just learning ansible. From the best of my knowledge, it seems apt module does not have a key named 'pkg'. Probably, what you are looking for is 'name' [1]

I think, changing following line

```
apt: pkg=curl update_cache=yes
```

with

```
apt: name=curl update_cache=yes
```

should solve the problem.

Ref:
http://docs.ansible.com/apt_module.html